# How to stop Cairo Dock minimizing Conky on Show Desktop?

Tags: 12.04, gnome, conky, cairo-dock

Every time I use Cairo Dock **Show Desktop** add-on Conky minimizes:

[image]

[image]

I've read about the `own_window_type override` option on `.conkyrc` and it seems to work for some people but it doesn't work for me. Conky won't show up if I use this option (it is currently set to `own_window_type normal`).

Any suggestions?

---

**.conkyrc**

```
# Conky settings #
background no
update_interval 1

cpu_avg_samples 2
net_avg_samples 2

override_utf8_locale yes

double_buffer yes
no_buffers yes

text_buffer_size 2048
#imlib_cache_size 0

temperature_unit fahrenheit

# Window specifications #

own_window yes
own_window_type normal
own_window_transparent yes
own_window_hints undecorate,sticky,skip_taskbar,skip_pager,below

border_inner_margin 0
border_outer_margin 0

minimum_size 200 250
maximum_width 200

alignment tr
gap_x 35
gap_y 55

# Graphics settings #
draw_shades no
draw_outline no
draw_borders no
draw_graph_borders no

# Text settings #
use_xft yes
override_utf8_locale yes
xftfont Neuropolitical:size=8
xftalpha 0.8
uppercase no

temperature_unit celsius

default_color FFFFFF

# Lua Load  #
lua_load ~/.lua/scripts/clock_rings.lua
lua_draw_hook_pre clock_rings

TEXT
${font Neuropolitical:size=42}${time %e}
${goto 100}${font Neuropolitical:size=18}${color FF3300}${voffset -75}${time %b}
${font Neuropolitical:size=10}${color FF3300}${voffset 15}${time %A}${color FF3300}${hr}
${goto 100}${font Neuropolitical:size=15}${color FFFFFF}${voffset -35}${time %Y}
${font Neuropolitical:size=30}${voffset 40}${alignc}${time %H}:${time %M}
${goto 175}${voffset -30}${font Neuropolitical:size=10}${time %S}
${voffset 10}${font Neuropolitical:size=11}${color FF3300}${alignr}HOME${font}
${font Neuropolitical:size=13}${color FFFFFF}${alignr}temp: ${weather http://weather.noaa.gov/pub/data/observations/metar/stations/ LQBK temperature temperature 30} °C${font}
${hr}
${image ~/.conky/logo.png -p 165,10 -s 35x35}
${color FFFFFF}${font Neuropolitical:size=8}Uptime: ${uptime_short}
${color FFFFFF}${font Neuropolitical:size=8}Processes: ${processes}
${color FFFFFF}${font Neuropolitical:size=8}Running: ${running_processes}

${color FF3300}${goto 125}${voffset 27}CPU
${color FFFFFF}${goto 125}${cpu cpu0}%
${color FF3300}${goto 125}${voffset 55}RAM
${color FFFFFF}${goto 125}${memperc}%
${color FF3300}${goto 125}${voffset 56}Swap
${color FFFFFF}${goto 125}${swapperc}%
${color FF3300}${goto 125}${voffset 57}Disk
${color FFFFFF}${goto 125}${fs_used_perc /}%
${color FF3300}${goto 130}${voffset 55}Net
${color FFFFFF}${goto 130}${downspeed eth0}
${color FFFFFF}${goto 130}${upspeed eth0}

${color FF3300}${font Neuropolitical:size=8}${alignr}${nodename}
${color FF3300}${font Neuropolitical:size=8}${alignr}${pre_exec cat /etc/issue.net}  $machine
${color FF3300}${font Neuropolitical:size=8}${alignr}Kernel: ${kernel}
${hr}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
own_window_type panel
```

using **panel** instead of normal or override should fix your problem, i.e. keep your conky window visible through show_desktop function calls from cairo dock (or other programs)

See below extract from the conky documentation for other settings:

from:   http://conky.sourceforge.net/config_settings.html

> if own_window is yes, you may specify type normal, desktop, dock,
>   panel or override (default: normal). Desktop windows are special
>   windows that have no window decorations; are always visible on your
>   desktop; do not appear in your pager or taskbar; and are sticky across
>   all workspaces. Panel windows reserve space along a desktop edge, just
>   like panels and taskbars, preventing maximized windows from
>   overlapping them. The edge is chosen based on the alignment option.
>   Override windows are not under the control of the window manager.
>   Hints are ignored. This type of window can be useful for certain
>   situations.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but for an updated answer in **2022** on **Ubuntu 22.04.1**,

```
own_window_type desktop
```

does the job, as opposed to the accepted answer says to use <strike>`panel`</strike>. Panel would take a dedicated space on the screen and it won't let you maximize any other window over it. So use `desktop` to solve this issue if you are using newer versions of Conky and Ubuntu.

Edit: Apparently the definition had the same information ever since but for some reason the accepted answer has panel as the answer. Just wanted to clarify and acknowledge the definition.

From: https://conky.cc/config_settings#own_window_type

> **Desktop windows are special windows that have no window decorations;
> are always visible on your desktop; do not appear in your pager or
> taskbar; and are sticky across all workspaces**. Panel windows reserve
> space along a desktop edge, just like panels and taskbars, preventing
> maximized windows from overlapping them. The edge is chosen based on
> the alignment option.

Comment: Worked for me, and I also want to share a [link](https://conky.cc/config_settings#own_window_type) about it